# include extjs 5 library in my web site

Tags: web, include, extjs5

How add Extjs full library on my web site? I Added

```
ext-theme-classic-all-debug.css
and 
ext-all.js
```

but it still not works.

I Have bugs sometimes I got message "show is undefined" and sometimes other errors..

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have got it. it's

```
ext/build/bootstrap.js
```